# How to use chi-squared (or Bayesian) to detect non-chance variations in matrix of frequencies?

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test

I've got a database showing signatures added to a petition, with each signature linked to a location (city, state), a date, and a sequence in the date (e.g. the seventh signature on 3/26 came from Rochester, NY).

I'd like to detect geographic patterns in the data - e.g. when one signature from Rochester leads to further signatures from Rochester, and also when a signature from Rochester leads to a signature from San Francisco or Fairbanks).

To simplify for the moment, I can look just a signatures by day, ignoring sequence w/i day and construct a matrix - one row for each location, one column for each location. The value of each cell is the observed frequency of one or more signatures from the column location on a day, when there was at least one signature from the row location on the previous day.

Clearly, if there is no geographic linkage, the values for each cell in a given column will be identical. Clearly, also, chance variations will lead to slight variations in cell values down the column, even if there is no geographic linkage.

What statistic should I use to determine whether, in general, there is some geographic dependency - that it helps to know which locations provided signatures yesterday in order to predict which locations will provide signatures today? (I.e. my null hypothesis is that knowing which locations generated signatures yesterday doesn't help to predict which locations will generate signatures today.)

What statistic should I use to detect specific dependencies? In particular, I'm guessing that some locations provide signatures at random, while other locations are driven either by activity within that location (e.g. a bunch of activists in Fairbanks, AK work every day to round up signatures), or even between locations (San Francisco activists press for lots of SF signatures on Monday, then contact their colleagues in LA on Tuesday, etc.). In this case, I have a null hypothesis for each location X: Knowing which locations (incl. X) generated signatures yesterday doesn't help to predict whether X in particular will generate signatures today.

From my long-ago stats course, I'm thinking chi-squared, but I'd be grateful for more detailed pointers.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on why you want to "detect geographic patterns"?  After all, there *will* be patterns, because there are strong geographic patterns in population distribution.  Therefore it would help to know what these "patterns" might mean for you: what would they explain or reveal?  How would they help you act in the future?